# 404 page not found when trying to use Gqlgen with julienschmidt/httprouter

Tags: go, graphql, gqlgen, httprouter

Below is the code I run
the issue is that I get 404 page not found instead of the graphql playground page
Is it possible to work with httprouter with gqlgen or do I need to go back to chi or mux
I also was not able to use middlewares because r does not have Use method

```
package main

import (
    "gographql-server/graph"
    "gographql-server/graph/generated"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql/handler"
    "github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql/playground"
    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
)

const defaultPort = "8080"

func PlaygroundHandler() httprouter.Handle {
    h := playground.Handler("GraphQL", "/query")

    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
        h.ServeHTTP(w, req)
    }
}

func GraphqlHandler() httprouter.Handle {
    h := handler.NewDefaultServer(generated.NewExecutableSchema(generated.Config{Resolvers: &graph.Resolver{}}))

    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
        h.ServeHTTP(w, req)
    }
}

func main() {
    port := os.Getenv("PORT")
    if port == "" {
        port = defaultPort
    }
    r := httprouter.New()
    r.POST("/query", GraphqlHandler())
    r.GET("/", PlaygroundHandler())
    // r.Use(middleware.RequestID)
    // r.Use(middleware.Logger)
    // r.Use(middleware.Recoverer)
    // r.Use(middlewares.AuthMiddleware())
    log.Printf("connect to http://localhost:%s/ for GraphQL playground", port)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, nil))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass `nil` to [`http.ListenAndServe()`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ListenAndServe) in this line:

```
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, nil))
```

That means the [`DefaultServeMux`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#DefaultServeMux) of the `net/http` package is used. But you you don't register any handlers in the default mux, you create your own router using [`httprouter.New()`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter#New), and you register handlers in that.

So you must pass this router to `ListenAndServe()`:

```
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, r))
```